# Как ограничить 8 cимволов до разделителя reg exp JS

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение, которое ограничивает число символов после разделителя (максимум 2), как добавить в это выражение ограничение ввода 8 символов до разделителя?

```
let regexp = /^\d+[.,]?\d{0,2}$/
```

Comment: это у вас число с 1-8 знаками в целой части и возможными двумя знаками после запятой, или что?

Comment: да, верно, должно быть число

Answer (score 2, accepted):

такое что ли? https://regex101.com/r/cQN1N0/1

```
^\d{1,8}(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$
```

в общем говоря у вас есть от 1 до 8 цифр с начала строки `^\d{1,8}`
далее следует необязательная часть   `()?`   и конец `$`
захватывать ее не надо, поэтому так `(?:)?`
и собственно ее содержимое - разделитель и 1-2 разряда. `[.,]\d{1,2}`.

Comment: webpack не дает собрать проект, ругается на регулярное выражение 
let regexp = /^\d{1,8}(?>[.,]\d{1,2})?$/

Comment: @vsemozhebuty откуда вы тут просмотр назад взяли, особенно при условии что все шаги расписаны текстом?

Comment: @PotroNik отредактировал